# Gmail Attachments Reordered Incorrectly by Gmail

Tags: gmail

When I attach several images to my Gmail in the order I want to match the document description and then mail the whole, every time Gmail changes the order of my attachments.

I have a Galaxy 8+ running Android 8.0.0 and Gmail 8.6.3.200445973.release @2018 Google Inc.

I am frustrated because everywhere I search sites like this site it tells me Gmail does not do this. Yes, it does it to me all the time!

It has gotten so frustrating, when I must have attachments in the correct order I have stopped using Gmail for that. Instead I use Samsung Email. It does not resort my attachments.

Is there some way to correct Gmail to get it to behave properly? I do not see anything in the settings to correct the problem.

Comment: I had this issue one time with desktop Gmail: attached 4 images (they were named in alphabetical order), 1 of them been attached in wrong order.

Comment: No email ever guarantees the order of attachments. In any case, this is about the Android app and not the web interface, and so is off-topic here.